# Is there a way to interrogate the status of AS400 jobs from VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to provide a user interface in Access to display the status of scheduled AS400 jobs, to show them as either pending, running, or complete.

I've inherited some code which schedules several jobs, which runs fine - but there's no way the user can see what the job status is, and they sometimes hang.

Completion is currently signaled via a numeric counter held in the tables which the jobs update, and there's a Form Timer event which regularly checks for completion.

Using this method, the code can tell when processing on the AS400 is complete, but not if it's hung or failed, or if the server is heavily loaded and running slowly.

I've tried to find code examples on the internet but drew a blank. All I could find that helped was the IBM Database Manual (pdf and online) and a pdf slideshow entitled "iSeries Access ActiveX Development" by Troy C Bleeker of IBM.

Using these resources, I've written some code using the IBM i Access for Windows ActiveX Object Library (cwbx) to talk to the AS400 which works fine, and I can issue the WRKUSRJOB command to check job statuses, but I can't figure out how (or even if) it's possible to view the results of the command.

Is there a way of doing this, and if so, how?

````
Dim SysNames As New cwbx.SystemNames
Dim SvrName As String
Dim Svr As New cwbx.AS400System
Dim Svc As cwbx.cwbcoServiceEnum
Dim Cmd As New cwbx.Command
Dim x As New cwbx.DataQueue

'Set server name
SvrName = SysNames.DefaultSystem
Debug.Print SvrName
Svr.Define SvrName

'Set service type
Svc = cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd

'Connect and test
Svr.Connect Svc
Debug.Print Svr.IsConnected(Svc)

'Command
Set Cmd.System = Svr
Debug.Print "WRKUSRJOB"
Cmd.Run "WRKUSRJOB"

```
'How to get results of the command? Nothing in Errors
Debug.Print SprintF("Errors: %s", Cmd.Errors.Count)
```

'Tidy up
Svr.Disconnect Svc

'Object destruction
Set Cmd = Nothing
Set Svr = Nothing
Set SysNames = Nothing
````

It would be great if eg the Errors collection contained the results of the command, or if they could be piped or redirected to a file or queue that could be read by the ActiveX, but I keep drawing a blank.

Edit: My client has v7r1 installed and is phasing out db2 so there is no possibility of an upgrade to a more recent version.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using a supported version of IBM i,

Take a look at [Db2 for i Services](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/DB2%20for%20i%20-%20Services)...

Specifically the
QSYS2.ACTIVE_JOB_INFO()
QSYS2.GET_JOB_INFO()

example:

```
select *
from table (QSYS2.GET_JOB_INFO('123456/MYUSER/MYJOB')) as X;
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, this sounds like a promising avenue - at least it should return a recordset to ODBC. I tried running `SELECT * FROM TABLE (QSYS2.ACTIVE_JOB_INFO()) X` but got an error: "ODBC--call failed. [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - ACTIVE_JOB_INFO in QSYS2 type *N not found. (#-204)". Does this mean we're not using a supported version of IBM i? If so, is there a way around this using the API or is that, too, doomed to failure?

Comment: @Belladonna appears you're on an outdated version of the OS, perhaps v7.1?  In that case, the [work management APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/wm1.htm) are your only choice.  You might be able to call them directly as an external stored procedure, but it'd be lots easier for you to comsume them if an RPG/CL/COBOL wrapper was created for you to call.

Comment: Thanks Charles, another useful pointer. I found an [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzaik/rzaikclcmd.htm) which says I can use the following syntax to call a CL command: `call qsys2.qcmdexc('STRDBG UPDPROD(*YES)',20)`. This is the method used in the code I've inherited, so I know it works, which is encouraging. I was thinking, if there were a CL command to print the job list to a file (rather than the console), I could then retrieve the file contents... but I'm struggling to find one in the documentation. Does anything come to mind?

Comment: For example, it would be lovely if `CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('WRKUSRJOB USER(XXXXX) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/TEST1)',59)` would work, but unfortunately WRKUSRJOB doesn't allow redirection of its output to file.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I think I've finally cracked it.

The solution is to use two passthrough queries:

1. Dump the job log to file using the CL command [DSPJOBLOG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/dspjoblog.htm)
2. Read the contents of the newly-created file

```
CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC('DSPJOBLOG OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(XXXXXXXX/TEST1)',50)

SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXX.TEST1
```

Many thanks for the suggestions and pointers, in particular to Charles for all the detailed DB2 knowledge, and to Mandy for a crucial clarification.

@Charles I upvoted your answer but unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation yet for it to show publicly.

Comment: You do need to get into the services as described by Charles if you are going to do more of this stuff, though, that is IBM's clear direction of travel and I would doubt that the CL commands that are missing outfile support will get it now.

Comment: Thanks Mandy, I would definitely agree, and would have loved to have used Charles's suggestions if only they'd been available on our platform! Unfortunately, db2 here is gradually being phased out at my client's site, so I just have to work with what they've got. I found something this morning which indicates we have v7r1, which would that make sense given that - frustratingly - ACTIVE_JOB_INFO and GET_JOB_INFO were added in v7r2.

Answer (score -1):

Is there not some command for the AS400 that returns the job status?

I don't know as400, but something like WRKACTJOB, or whatever command to list out jobs must exist? I don't see any reason to use some special API.

If you have or can setup a command in as400 to return the job status(s), then in access you can simply use a PT query  with that command as the sql text.

It not clear if you  looking to query a specific job, or just display all jobs? So, if you have some as400 code or command that returns the job status, then place that command in a PT query, and base your form on that PT query. You can then add a timer to re-display say every 5 seconds or whatever you want. By using a PT query in Access, then really little if any code need be written in Access.

Comment: I tried that already but it doesn't work, I get ODBC - Call Failed, Token WRKACTJOB is not valid. Valid tokens: (END GET SET... etc. If it worked, it would be so elegant! To answer your question, I am looking for several specific jobs and have the user name under which they were submitted, and the names of the jobs.

Comment: Well, we assume the PT query works for some commends? There must be some kind of SELECT type return that you have for active jobs.

Comment: WRKACTJOB expects to have a green screen to put its output on, as do all shipped WRK... CL commands, so even if you invoked it somehow from SQL you would not get anything useful back. @Charles' answer is the right way to get the result set you suggest.

Comment: As @MandyShaw says, WRKACTJOB outputs to the 5250 screen.  If you want to work with job information programmatically, you can use the old school APIs or the newer Db2 for i SQL services.  From VBA, the SQL services are the easiest.  The OP would probably need an RPG/COBOL/CL wrapper to work with the APIs

Comment: But does not simply entering a query also just output to the screen? a pass-though query in Access sends whatever you would type at the command prompt anyway. So, if you can setup a program, command or whatever, and it returns rows of data to the screen, then that is simply sent to access.

Comment: Entirely depends what environment you are running the sql from. If you are using STRSQL, or STRQMQRY, yes, it will appear on the green screen. If you are in any other environment, you get a result set which your program can do what it likes with. Like with any other database platform that supports sql. The OP wants to do specific processing on the output in their code, I think.

Comment: Sure so Charles answer below as a PT query  from Access should work just fine - that's my whole point.

Comment: My (new) understanding is that only table functions and views will return recordsets to ODBC, so eg ACTIVE_JOB_INFO() and JOB_INFO() - which are table functions - and eg JOB_QUEUE_INFO - which is a view - will work. But standard functions like WRKACTJOB will not work with a passthrough query as they don't return recordsets to ODBC. So your answer was in the right direction (passthrough query) but wasn't ultimately helpful as SELECT * FROM WRKACTJOB won't work, and neither you nor I knew enough about DB2 to know how to fix it.

Comment: I can no longer edit my previous comment, just to add that Albert's original suggestion was to "simply use a PT query with that command as the sql text" (so, no SELECT * FROM) - which doesn't work.

Comment: WRKACTJOB is an IBM i operating system command, it has nothing at all to do with DB2, I think that may be the source of some confusion here.

Comment: Charles post below shows such a select - if that select returns data, then that select should work just fine as a PT query from Access. PT query in Access only really sends RAW commands to the system as if you had typed them in.  For commands that don't return a result dataset, then my suggestion will not work. If command below as Charles has will return a valid data set, then such a commend can be "sent" from Access as a PT query. The "text" in a PT query from Access is sent un-changed. You can send any command you want, but of course it has to return data to return something of use to Access

Comment: Thanks Mandy, that's a helpful clarification/distinction.